# angular 2 jsPDF. Property data not reflecting in PDF

Tags: angular, jspdf

I am using jsPDF to generate PDF from HTML. When I click the download button first PDF did not reflect the updated title. If I hit the button again it starts reflecting the updated title. I tried to debug it and found innerHTML for DIV not reflecting immediately after property got changed. Once I hit the button again it picks the updated property from the last hit and reflects value.

HTML Code:-

```
<button (click)="onGenerate()">Download Invoice</button>

<div #invoicePDF style="display: block;">
  {{pdfTitle}}
</div>
```

Component Code:-

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export class GroupComponent {
private pdfTitle = "Initial Title";

@ViewChild('invoicePDF') invoicePDF: ElementRef;

public onGenerate(){ 
    this.pdfTitle = "Updated Title";

    const doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    let content = this.invoicePDF.nativeElement;

    let specialElementHandler = {
      '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
      }
    };

    doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 200,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandler
    }, function() {
      doc.save('Invoice.pdf');
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you try adding PDF creation code inside setTimeout() / Zone.run()

Comment: Can you please provide sample code??

Comment: setTimeout(()=>{doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, {
      'width': 200,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandler
    }, function() {
      doc.save('Invoice.pdf');
    })}, 0)

Comment: It's working. Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Ok. UpVote the same in the answer. Keep Learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the PDF creation code inside setTimeout() block. This will notify Angular to trigger change detection.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
      doc.fromHTML(content.innerHTML, 15, 15, { 
        'width': 200, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandler }, 
         function() { doc.save('Invoice.pdf'); 
      })},
 0);
```